# Unable to import model form model of another app

Tags: django, django-models

This is code of transactions.model
here i am trying to import WalletUser model form WalletUser.models

```
import uuid as uuid
from django.db import models
from walletApp.WalletUser.models import WalletUser

class Transaction(models.Model):
STATUS_TYPES = (
    ('C', 'Compleat'),
    ('S', 'Success'),
    ('I', 'Incompleat'),
    ('A', 'aborted'),
)
uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_TYPES, default='N', max_length=3)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)
user = models.ForeignKey(WalletUser)
amount = models.FloatField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.uuid
```

I am getting this error

```
/Users/shoaib/Documents/walletTransactionSystem/walletApp/walletApp/settings.py changed, 
reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File             "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File     "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/shoaib/Documents/walletTransactionSystem/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/shoaib/Documents/walletTransactionSystem/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/shoaib/Documents/walletTransactionSystem/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/shoaib/Documents/walletTransactionSystem/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/shoaib/Documents/walletTransactionSystem/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/shoaib/Documents/walletTransactionSystem/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/shoaib/Documents/walletTransactionSystem/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/shoaib/Documents/walletTransactionSystem/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/shoaib/Documents/walletTransactionSystem/walletApp/transaction/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from walletApp.WalletUser.models import WalletUser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'walletApp.WalletUser'
```

I tried walletApp.WalletUser.models and WalletUser.models too both are not working.
WalletUser.models is straight up giving.
PLZ help I am stuck

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'transaction',
    'Wallet',
    'WalletUser',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

Comment: GIT HUB :: link = https://github.com/shoaib4/-walletTransactionSystem-

Answer (score 0):

```py
from WalletUser.models import WalletUser
```

You are very close! Since your app is in the same directory as the base, you don't need to specify base directory, you can just import the models from the app.